# How to move the paragraph to the left on CSS and HTML on phone size scre

Tags: html, css

It looks pefectly in the normal 16:9 computer screen with word on left side and picture on the right side.
But when it comes to smaller screen like a phone size screen,it does appears a picture on top of the paragraph like I want to. I am pretty new  to this, so please help.

this is my media file for that

[image]

```
@media(max-width: 700px){
    
   
    .project1-img{
        flex-basis: 10%;
        width: 350px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    
    .project-one{
        float: right;
        width: 750px;
        margin: 20px;
        padding-left: 10px;  
        inline-size: 1000px;
    }   
}
```

I need a code to help me align paragraph to a desire position

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

**What you want to do exactly?**
I guess you want the para and image both visible on the phone screen. So you can do that using flex property of CSS
Here is the example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        .image img{
            width:500px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .content{
            width: 500px;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .row{
            display: flex;
        }

        @media (max-width:760px){
            .row{
                flex-direction: column;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col content">
            <h1>Some Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, id praesentium nesciunt vitae libero pariatur. Nam earum reiciendis error autem porro dicta officiis ullam. Alias, minima! Laborum natus maiores rem!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661961112835-ca6f5811d2af?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1172&q=80" alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**If this is not what you want to do then explain in detail what you want to do..along with your whole code (html file)**